# TeXworks spell checker doesn't mark any misspelled words

Tags: texworks, spelling

I've added three spell checkers to my TeXworks installation, and TeXworks has no problems finding them. But when I'm typing my `.tex` document, the spell checker doesn't do anything, even though the spell checker is activated (see picture below). How can I fix this?

Note, this is not a problem with the OS (Windows 7), because spell checkers work fine in other programs.

[image]

---

EDIT:

(1) Judging by later questions asked by other people (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283569/in-texworks-spell-check-is-not-working), this is not an issue unique to me.

(2) The issue still persists for me today on a different computer with Windows 7 and the latest versions of `texlive` and `TeXworks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 0.6 you should have no problem with spell checking anymore (see [release notes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeXworks/texworks/release-0.6.1/NEWS)). It should be fixed in all recent distributions (whether on Linux or Windows or ...).